# Monthly calendar is now entitled "Friday, August 1, 2014"

Tags: 7, datetime

My monthly calendar is now entitled "Friday, August 1, 2014" for all views and blocks that use the monthly calendar.  All other views like day, week, year are all fine I believe.  I just now noticed this when I updated just a few minutes ago to D7.31 from 7.29.  I also allowed the date module (and one other one and I can't remember right now...) to be updated.  Any ideas how to fix it?

Dave Niemeyer

Comment: Well I fixed it, I returned the site to DATE module ver 7.27 rather than 7.28 that was what got updated today, and the titles of MONTH views and blocks now read "August" rather than the first of the month.  Also, I didn't mention that other months, when this view got messed up with this updated Date module, also were entitled "First day of the month" like "September 1, 2014.  So now that's fixed for all months as well.  Has anyone else seen this problem?  Is there a fix besides going back to date module ver. 7.27?

Comment: see this bug report on the Calendar Module site (https://www.drupal.org/node/2317947). You should include your 'answer' as an answer and accept it